# modify csv structure using PHP before import to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv, import

I have a csv in .txt who need to be imported to **MySql** 
I'm importing it manualy to my table but it keep breaking giving me this error :
 Invalid column count in CSV input on line 706.

checking it on excel the only information who could make the problem is that one of the  cells contains :   ***5.5 x 18"***

```
  probably the quotation mark is doing it
```

how can i fix this for the import ? 
thank you

Comment: How are you trying to import into MySQL?  Are you using `LOAD DATA INFILE`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe all you need is this:

```
str_replace('"', '\"', $value);
```

By replacing the " with \" you are escaping it and it should insert properly.

Comment: Not necessarily true if the file uses `"` to delimit fields, which it seems it may if he is getting invalid column count.  Doing this would escape all the delimiters as well.